# Blazor with Bootstrap (form-select)

Tags: html, visual-studio, bootstrap-4, blazor

I'm brand new to Blazor and want to use the classes from bootstrap but somehow when I use the class form-selcet the browser doesn't read the class

```
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
            <select name="" id="" class="form-select">
                <option disabled selected>Anrede</option>
                <option>Herre</option>
                <option>Damen</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are pulling in Bootstrap 5 - Blazor templates default to bootstrap 4.3

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap v4 and lower (which are generally the default for current projects) you must use the `form-control` class, not the `form-select` class:

```
<div class="col-md-3 ">
    <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
        <option disabled selected>Anrede</option>
        <option>Herre</option>
        <option>Damen</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my answers so it is not that brief. The information is still the same, and could be an answer, depending on what they are using